# PHP URL encoding with HTTP GET request

Tags: php, urlencode

I've set up a PHP script to send a text message using the Nexmo API, however there's a problem with how I'm encoding the HTTP [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request. The script pulls some variables from stored data, and then fires. I'm not experienced with PHP and have spent so much time on this already, this is my last resort, is anyone able to see where I've gone wrong in the following code?

The intended format for the request:

```
https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?api_key=XXX&api_secret=XXX&to=XXX&from=XXX&text=XXX
```

The code:

```
function sendText () {

    $api_key = $settings['consumer_key'];
    $api_secret = $settings['consumer_secret'];
    $recipient = $settings['recipient'];
    $from = $settings['from'];
    $text = $settings['sms_contents'];

    $url = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json';
    $data = array_merge($data, array('api_key' => $api_key, 'api_secret' => $api_secret, 'to' => $recipient, 'from' => $from, 'text' => $text));

    $post = '';
    foreach($data as $k => $v) {
        $post .= "&$k=$v";
    }

    $opts = array('http' =>
            array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'content' => $post
            )
        );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $from_nexmo = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

}

sendText();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) for transferred values:

```
$post = array();

foreach($data as $k => $v){
    $post[] = $k . '=' . urlencode($v);
}

$post = implode('&', $post);

$opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $post
        )
    );
```

Comment: @Jeremy Hewitt , Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you are doing any encoding. Here is what I would do:

```
foreach($data as $k => $v){
    $post .= "&$k=" . urlencode($v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try executing the following code snippet:

```
function sendText () {

    $api_key = $settings['consumer_key'];
    $api_secret = $settings['consumer_secret'];
    $recipient = $settings['recipient'];
    $from = $settings['from'];
    $text = $settings['sms_contents'];

    $url = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json';
    $data = array_merge($data, array('api_key' => $api_key, 'api_secret' => $api_secret, 'to' => $recipient, 'from' => $from, 'text' => $text));

    $post = http_build_query($data);

    $opts = array('http' =>
            array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'content' => $post
            )
        );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $from_nexmo = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
}

sendText();
```